# Why a new M1 brand new Mac takes so long to start after login?

Tags: macos, performance, login, monterey

I have no application starting or loading anything when the mac starts.

I start my mac, see the login window, type my password and after that it takes a long time to login. I guess 2 to 4 minutes to login while the progress bar slowly advances.

I remember when this mac was new, 2 months ago and it would take seconds after typing the password to see the desktop and be able to operate the computer but with time, this time increased and there are days worse than others, where it takes longer.

I am proficient on terminal and other advanced stuff, if your explanation requires that.

Is there something I can do to make this faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@SolarMike comment gave me other ideas and I have discovered the culprit. I have two USB disks permanently connected to my computer. Those take time to mount and makes the computer slow to login. Apple should mount these on the background just after showing the desktop.

I will try to replace those with SSD in the near future to make it less annoying.

NOTE:

I have discovered the problem.

The problem is that I had all my USB disks formatted with APFS. **DON'T DO THAT IF YOU ARE USING NON-SSD DISKS**.

I was forced to use an old mac to reformat those disks using encrypted journaled HFS+ disks (thanks to Apple, Monterey is not able to format disks using HFS+) and the problem was solved.

Comment: Mounting an HD should **not** take **minutes**... to me it sounds there is some other issue at work here. Did you check the health of those HDs? Or are you saying that macOS is *indexing* the HDs before showing you the "desktop"? Because indexing *could* take minutes depending on the number of files/directories.

Comment: as far as I know there is no way to check the health of those USB HDs, by SMART status, I mean. I have did a check disk on them and they show no errors but both take from 2 to 4 minutes to mount. They are USB disks connected thru a USB-C to USB adapter. The disks are encrypted. One of the disks is a One Touch HD (non SSD), 5TB disk. If you know something I can do to check that, I appreciate.